# How to stop a python click event from firing again until the first one is done?

Tags: python, events, mouseclick-event

When using mouse click event on python, Multiple clicks happen at once. This makes loops to have problem working with a variable that is constantly changing.

I want to single thread it. Stop the click event until all the functionalities in that thread is done, then listen for more.

I am also not sure why I am getting multiple clicks at once. Every time I click, it fires 3 times. That's why I want to ask this question overall to solve this issue.

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import TextArea, DrawingArea, OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from mpl_point_clicker import clicker


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def isAround(self, anotherPoint):
        if anotherPoint.x == self.x + 1 or anotherPoint.x == self.x - 1 or anotherPoint.x == self.y + 1 or anotherPoint.x == self.y - 1:
            return True
        return False

    def roundPoints(self):
        self.x = round(self.x, 2)
        self.y = round(self.y, 2)
            


mouseClicks = []
slopeAndLengths = []

count = 0


def on_pick(event):
    global count
    artist = event.artist
    xmouse, ymouse = event.mouseevent.xdata, event.mouseevent.ydata
    x, y = artist.get_xdata(), artist.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    # print ('Artist picked:', event.artist)
    # print ('{} vertices picked'.format(len(ind)))
    print ('Pick between vertices {} and {}'.format(min(ind), max(ind)+1))
    # print ('x, y of mouse: {:.2f},{:.2f}'.format(xmouse, ymouse))
    # print ('Data point:', x[ind[0]], y[ind[0]])
    # print(" ------------------- ")
    thisPoint = Point(x[ind[0]], y[ind[0]])
    thisPoint.roundPoints()
    mouseClicks.append(thisPoint)
    for i in range(len(mouseClicks)):
        for j in list(range(len(mouseClicks))):
            if mouseClicks[i].isAround(mouseClicks[j]):
                if not mouseClicks[i] == mouseClicks[j]:
                    mouseClicks.pop(i)
    print(mouseClicks)
    # mouseClicks.append((round(x[ind[0]],2),round(y[ind[0]],2)))
    # count += 1
    # if count % 2 == 0:
    #     mouseClicks.pop()
    #     print(mouseClicks)
    

    if len(mouseClicks)==2:
        length = mouseClicks[1].x - mouseClicks[0].x
        slope = (mouseClicks[1].y - mouseClicks[0].y)/(mouseClicks[1].x - mouseClicks[0].x)

        slopeAndLengths.append((round(slope,2),round(length,2)))
        mouseClicks.pop(0)
        # print(slopeAndLengths)
        # print(mouseClicks)

    # addPoint(round(x[ind[0]],2),round(y[ind[0]],2))
    # ax.plot(round(x[ind[0]],2),round(y[ind[0]],2),'bo-', zorder=2)
    # plt.draw()
    

arr_lena = mpimg.imread('picture.png')
imageBox = OffsetImage(arr_lena, zoom=2)

ab = AnnotationBbox(imageBox, (7.4, 13.6), zorder=1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.add_artist(ab)

for row in range(1,30):
    tolerance = 30 # points
    ax.plot(np.arange(0,15,0.5),[i*row/i for i in range(1,15*2+1)], 'ro-', picker=tolerance, zorder=0)


fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', on_pick)
klicker = clicker(ax, ["event"], markers=["x"], **{"linestyle": "--"})


plt.draw()
plt.savefig('add_picture_matplotlib_figure.png',bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

I have tried this idea to remove points that are near the first received point, but because multiple threads happen at once, this doesn't help.

```
for i in range(len(mouseClicks)):
        for j in list(range(len(mouseClicks))):
            if mouseClicks[i].isAround(mouseClicks[j]):
                if not mouseClicks[i] == mouseClicks[j]:
                    mouseClicks.pop(i)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

How I fix it was like this:

before I go to the answer, we know that every time a click is received, on_pick function will run. So using time I could dismiss the event fires that were happening at the same time, leaving only one of them.

Answer:

```
Before = datetime.now()

def on_pick(event):
    global Before
    now = datetime.now()
    if (now < Before + timedelta(seconds=1)):
        return
    Before = datetime.now()
    ...
```